# how to avoid event overlapping on dates using fullcalendar?

Tags: php, fullcalendar

So in my case, I have 3 cases: 
C1: contain dates from 29 to 31
C2: contain dates from 1 to 3 and then 5 to 6 but not 4th
C3: contain single date 4th

Now, what I am trying to achieve here is to display C2 event from 1 to 3 and 5 to 6 but its displaying on 4th date as well. However, it shouldn't display on 4th because it's part of other case (c3)

Following is the image:
[image]

My data is coming from database and that's the reason I have to display my start: 2020/04/1 and end: 2020/04/6 because of this it's selecting 4th date as well. Which is the issue for me.

My code:

```
id: "2",
                    title: 'C - 2',
                    start: '2020-04-01T12:00:00', 
                    description: 'case 2',
                    end: '2020-04-06T15:30:00',
                    className: "bg_green fa fa-edit",
                    //eventTextColor: "white",

                }
```

So how I can skip the 4th date here or may be group of dates as not part of this event?
Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if anyone have any ideas I was looking from last 4hours and trying different solutions but none of them work for me:( I tried eventOverlap but not getting it right as not sure how I can create the work around for my case

Comment: If you don't want C2 to go continously across the whole time period then it's simple - you just have to split C2 into two separate events.

Comment: Not sure how I can split C2 into two parts as its coming from database table. So I am extracting the records by cid=2 which gives me record of 1,2,3,5,6 dates. Wondering whats the best way to split this? Do you have any idea around this?

Comment: "as its coming from database table"...you'll have to intercept it and process it manually into separate events, then. You'll have to write an algorithm which detects conflicts between events (due to overlapping dates) and splits them into non-overlapping sections, before passing the new data to fullCalendar. Probably not a particularly simple task. It this really 100% necessary for you? I don't think I have fully understood why it's a problem to display these overlapping events to users?

Comment: P.S. fullCalendar just displays what you give to it, it doesn't have any built-in ability to do what you want. The eventOverlap setting is only applied when you're dragging an event around on the calendar.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I also thought that fullCalendar is not providing the adjustment I want so it's better to adjust my code. Won't like to adjust this on code side but I guess that's the last option I have