# how to divide table records with two sets of date group in mysql/php?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to split the following records:

[image]

So what SQL query I should try to split records into two? Please keep in mind that the record needs to divided bases on dates sequences. As may we get the case that sel_Date may receive like 01,02,03 - Group1 05,06 as Group-2 and Group-3 will be 12,13,14 so they all need to split properly.

Not sure even if this is possible.

This question is related to my other question here: 
[fullcalendar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983393/how-to-avoid-event-overlapping-on-dates-using-fullcalendar?noredirect=1#comment107897640_60983393)

Comment: you should add a column where you mark the groups.

Comment: Do you have a rule specifying the groups?  Or do you just want 3 records in one group and 2 in the other?

Comment: @nbk how ? do you have any particular example ? Is it not possible without it? like through query or on php side?

Comment: @GordonLinoff groups can be differ as this is just the example as sel_Date can be 11,12,13 or 21,22,23,24 so it will be different

Comment: your SQL query should `ORDER BY sel_date`. When outputting the rows, keep a track of the previous date, and if there's a gap of != 1, insert a "group barrier", whatever that is.

Comment: Please add you data as text, for mysql 5 and 8  are different solutions, so what are you using

Comment: @danblack is thr any other way then that? as I already thought that idea before asking here. Sorry but looking for more future prof solution here.

Comment: @nbk yes my data is stored as text and the version of my phpmyadmin is 4.8.3 not sure what this could help here.

Comment: the mysql version can be obtained with `SELECT VERSION()`. What future proofing are you after?

Comment: I mean your data you showed us as picture, put them as **text** in your question and not as image.

Comment: @danblack future proofing is more likely to do through the smarter sql query rather than getting the data first then track of previous date and place some if conditions. As that's I don't want it. I already think about that before came to stackoverflow